# Unable to resize the azure map in angular

Tags: angular, azure-maps

I'm new to **Angular and Azure Maps**. I downloaded the npm package `ng-azure-maps`. The  component does not increase its size upon adding styles to it in the app-component.css.

I tried `azure-map{width:100%; height:100vh;}` But it is not changing the size of the rendered map.

How can I change the size of the rendered map ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try raising this as an issue on that Github project as this issue appears to be localized to it. https://github.com/arnaudleclerc/ng-azure-maps

Comment: Hi, I'm the one working on this library. The azure-map tag is not a component but a directive, therefore it doesn't have any style applied on the library itself. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve and I'm terrible at css, but if your goal is to have a full size map, you could try adding a `position: absolute` style, like :

`azure-map {  position: absolute;  width:100%;  height:100vh;}`

There's also a couple of samples available on the git repository which might help you.

Comment: @Prem Kumar are you now unblocked? Please share the answer with us for others to learn. Thank you!

Comment: Hi sorry for the late comment. It is now working fine !!. Thanks a lot @ArnaudLeclerc for the wonderful library that you have developed.